# jQuery autocomplete disabled makes autocomplete partially transparent, not disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using the jQuery UI's "autocomplete" function on a search on my site. When you change a radio button from 'area search" to "name search" I want it to disable the autocomplete, and re-enable it when you switch back. However, when you disable the autocomplete it doesn't hide the dropdown, it just dims it to 20% opacity or so. Here's my javascript:

```
var allFields = new Array(<?php echo $allFields ?>);

$(document).ready(function() {

    if ($("input[name='searchType']:checked").val() == 'areaCode') {
        $("#siteSearch").autocomplete({
            source: allFields,
            minLength: 2
        });
    }

    $("input[name='searchType']").change(function(){
        if ($("input[name='searchType']:checked").val() == 'areaCode') {
            $( "#siteSearch" ).autocomplete( "option", "disabled", false );
            alert("enabled");
        }
        else {
            $( "#siteSearch" ).autocomplete( "option", "disabled", true );
            alert("disabled");
        }

    });

});
```

You can see it happening at http://crewinyourcode.com

First you have to chose an area code to search, and then you can see the issue.

EDIT:
I realize you have to choose an area code before you're given the option to switch search types. If you go to this URL you'll have both of them immediately:
http://crewinyourcode.com/search/choose-category/732/

Comment: I can't see the issue in the link you provided.

There is a "search by name" radio-button which doesn't make sense because there is no other radio-button to switch to! It will always be selected.

There is a LINK that says "search by area" and it brings up a search (the "search by name" radio-button is still selected though), but I can't get any auto-complete functionality to appear; it seems to be a plain text-box.

Comment: You can always search by name, but you can only search by area code once you've selected one. Once you choose an area code it remembers it and adds a second radio button. I should have provided a better link:

http://crewinyourcode.com/search/choose-category/732/

Start to type "Director" with it on "Search 732" and you'll see the autocomplete. Change it to "Search By Name" and you'll see an alert indicating the autocomplete is disabled (just testing code) and the autocomplete will still come up but faded, rather than hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added a CSS rule to display:hidden the autocomplete box. No biggie.